# How is the rate $H(X\mid Y)$ achieved in Slepian-Wolf coding?

Tags: entropy, information-theory, mutual-information, conditional-entropy

Given two (generally correlated) sources $X,Y$, [Slepian-Wolf coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slepian%E2%80%93Wolf_coding) is a protocol that shows it's possible to encode them separately, then have $X$ send $Y$ only $n H(X\mid Y)$ bits of information, and have $Y$ still be able to fully decode the $n$ bits produced by $X$.
In other words, the goal is for $Y$ to know the state of $X$, and we want the strategy to achieve this that requires $X$ to send as few bits as possible.

This is only one "regime" possible via Slepian-Wolf coding: more generally the point is that this encoding-decoding strategy is possible with rates satisfying $R_X\ge H(X\mid Y)$, $R_Y\ge H(Y\mid X)$, and $R_X+R_Y\ge H(X,Y)$, but let's focus on the case with $R_Y=H(Y)$, which allows $R_X=H(X\mid Y)<H(X)$.

I'm looking to understand the general idea behind this protocol. In particular, I'm trying to figure out whether it can be "simply" reduced to an encoding/decoding strategy based on typical sequences, as is often the case when discussing these types of transmission strategies in the asymptotic $n\to\infty$ limit (eg as the mutual information is achieved by encoding information in input typical sequences and using jointly typical sequences for decoding).

I found a simple example that is quite easy to understand in [these online (PDF) notes](http://www.mit.edu/%7E6.962/www_fall_2001/kusuma/summary.pdf), page 4:

> Suppose $X$ produces 3-bit sequences with equiprobable distribution, and $Y$ is never more than 1-bit away from $X$. For example, if $X=000$ then $Y\in\{000,100,010,001\}$. It is then sufficient for $X$ to send over 2 bits rather than 3, and still result in $Y$ knowing $X$'s state. The idea is that $X$ only needs to send over information necessary to distinguish between the four sets $\{000,111\}$, $\{100,011\}$, $\{010,101\}$, and $\{001,110\}$. There's 4 such cosets, hence 2 bits are sufficient. To decode, $Y$ now just needs to take the string in the received coset that is closer to what she had. For example, if $Y=000$, and $X$ sent over $\{010,101\}$, then the original state of $X$ was $010$ (as $101$ is not compatible with $Y=000$).

This is a nice illustration, but I'm not sure how general this type of strategy is. Especially due to the special structure of the correlations in this case (in fact, it's also a special case because the strategy works perfectly for every single triplet sent).
Is there a similarly "neat" way to understand the encoding-decoding strategy in a more general scenario?

Answer (score 1):

We can think of Slepian-Wolf Coding in terms of typical sequences.  The encoding protocol to achieve $(R_x, R_y) = (H(X), H(Y|X))$  is for the Encoder of $X$ to first losslessly transmit $X$ as done in the usual source coding theorem.  The Encoder of $Y$ will randomly partition all typical $Y^n$ sequences into one of $2^{nH(Y|X)}$ bins and send the bin index $M$.

After having decoded $X^n$ in the usual way, the decoder looks into bin $M$ and finds the unique $Y^n$ such that $(X^n, Y^n)$ are jointly typical.

Intuitively, there are only $2^{nH(Y|X)}$ sequences of $Y^n$ that are jointly typical with $X^n$.  So if we randomly partition these sequences into $2^{nH(Y | X)}$ bins, then with high probability there will only be one $Y^n$ in bin $M$ jointly typical with $X^n$